# Execute a .exe on a samba share

Tags: permissions, windows, samba

I have a linux machine and a windows machine, the linux machine has a samba share with a .exe file on it. I can read and write files from the windows machine to the samba share, but I cannot execute the .exe file. How can I setup samba to allow me to execute it?

Comment: I am indeed trying to execute it on my Windows Machine, the error is: "Windows cannot access \\CUBE-SERVER\share\xowa\xowa_64.exe You do not have permission to access \\CUBE-SERVER\share\xowa\xowa_64.exe. Contact your network administrator to request access."

Comment: Can you list the other files *in the \\CUBE-SERVER\share\xowa directory* on Windows? Can you read and write files *in that directory*?

Comment: The files are a bin folder, a user folder, a licence file, xowa.gfs, xowa_64.exe, xowa_build.gfs, xowa_build_windows_64, and xowa_windows_64.jar. I can read a write files to the directory, I tested this by making a txt file, typing in it, saving it, then reading it.

Comment: It may be a windows policy thing. (That's just about the extent of my windows knowledge :)

Answer (score 60):

This behavior because of a security policy of the modern Samba. Fix by adding this line to your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` under `[global]` section:

```
[global]
acl allow execute always = True
```

Source: [Samba's Wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_POSIX_ACLs#Making_Files_Executable).

Comment: This solved a problem for me running VS2017 on a Windows 10 vm where the solution was on a Linux mapped network drive.

Comment: Is there any more granular way, to say make only certain filetypes executable, like exe, bat, and msi?

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked by just adding the executable tag to the file.

```
chmod +x file.exe
```